# Update the data in amcharts in angular5

Tags: angular5, amcharts

I am using xy chart in amcharts as per my requirement.

In that amcharts, whenever on click of a bubble, I need to highlight the bubbles. So I have added listeners to my options as follows:

```
"listeners": [
      { 
          "event": "clickGraphItem",
          "method": function(event) {
            var bubbleId = event.item.dataContext.id;               
            var toolTip = "";               

            dataProvider.forEach((data) => {
                if (bubbleId != "" && bubbleId == data.id) {
                    if (data.bubbleSize == 10) {                            
                        data.bubbleSize = 20;
                        data.shape = "diamond";
                    } else {
                        data.bubbleSize = 10;
                        data.shape = "round";
                    }                       
                } else {
                    data.bubbleSize = 10;
                    data.shape = "round";
                }
            });
            this.AmCharts.updateChart(this.chart, () => {
                // Change whatever properties you want
                this.chart.dataProvider = dataProvider;
            });

          }
      }],
```

But I am getting an error as "Cannot read property 'Amcharts' of undefined". I am not able to resolve the issue. Can anyone help me on this?

Referal Code for Amcharts angular as follows:
https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2

Comment: `this` is likely referring to the event callback's scope rather than your class. Try capturing your class' this reference in a separate variable *outside of the listener* (e.g. `let _self = this;`) and then call updateChart with `_self.AmCharts.updateChart`

Comment: Yeah, I did that, it worked. But chart is not updated with new data even though dataProvider has updated data

Comment: Post a plunker with your setup. I'm not having any problems updating the dataProvider in `clickGraphItem` using similar code.

Comment: It's working. Thank you :)